# Pivot table - OpenERP 7.0

Tags: pivot, odoo, openerp-7

Is it possible to generate a pivot in OpenERP 7.0? 
I have a table with user, category and hours and I want to show that information split as a pivot table. Row: User - Column: Category, and sum of hours.

Would appreciate your responses. 
Thanks!